# Manhwa or manga where the main character rescues a boy and helps him but also ages him

Tags: story-identification, manga

The main character has black hair and blue eyes (his physical appearance is a kid) and when he was young he was put in charge of taking care of the class plants and they grew really well(time skip) he doesn’t grow like the rest of his classmates and he still looks like a little kid.

He ends up shutting himself away in a forest because his old village calls him a monster(time skip again) one day a boy gets sent to the forest as a sacrifice and the main tells him to 'go away' but the boy says 'no' because the people are rude to him (I think that’s the reason I don’t really remember). The protagonist ends up letting him stay but the boy gets hurt and the main character uses his powers to save him but he ended up making the boy become a teenager.

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?